# How I can update prometheus config file without losing data on docker

Tags: docker, prometheus, self-hosting

I have an docker container running prometheus and sometimes I have to update an config file inside the container, the problem is that I don't know who I can update this file without deleting and creating the container again.

```
 docker run --network="host" -d --name=prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v ~/prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml  prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

I want to know how I can update the **prometheus.yaml** without deleting and creating again the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You should VOLUME the data path of Prometheus outside of your container.
So if the container creates again, you can have your previous data.
The default data path of Prometheus is ./data but in docker it depends on your base-image.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can't since by principle containers are *ephemeral*. Meaning they're supposed to be *disposable* upon exiting. However, there are a few ways out of your predicament:

#1. Create a new Image from your running container: https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/ to persist the state.

#2. Copy your data from within the container to the "outside world" as a backup, if option 1 is not the right option for you (here's an explanation how to do so: https://linuxhandbook.com/docker-cp-example/). You could also log in to the container (`docker exec -it <container-name> bash`) and then use *yum* or *apt install* (depending on your base image) to install the necessary tools to make your backup (rsync, ...), if the sometimes *very* barebones baseimage does not provide these.

#3. As @Amir already mentioned, you should always create a Volume inside your Container and map it to the outside world to have a persistent data storage. You create a Volume by the *VOLUME*-Keyword in the Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ ..by doing so you can restart the container everytime if the config changes without worrying about data loss.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use the [reload](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) url

> Prometheus can reload its configuration at runtime. If the new configuration is not well-formed, the changes will not be applied. A configuration reload is triggered by sending a SIGHUP to the Prometheus process or sending a HTTP POST request to the /-/reload endpoint (when the --web.enable-lifecycle flag is enabled). This will also reload any configured rule files.

Use the following the change the config inside the container using:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> sh
```

Map the config to outside the docker container for persistence using

```
-v <host-path>:<container_path>
```